# JQuery show hide multiple DIVs from menu and menu within DIV

Tags: jquery, html, split

I'm new to JQuery. I'm trying to show and hide multiple divs. I have a menu showing A,B,C. When I click A, the div A1 appears. Div A1 has a menu within it showing 1, 2, 3 and so on. When I click 2 in this menu, A1 disappears and A2 appears. When I click B, the currently visible div disappears and B1 appears. B1 has a menu showing 1, 2, 3. When you click 2, B1 is replaced by B2. And so on - I think you get the picture.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="thework"><a href="#" class="A">A</a> <a href="#" class="B">B</a> <a href="#" class="C">C</a></div>
<div class="work-A-link1">A1<br />
<a href="#" class="link1">1</a> <a href="#" class="link2">2</a> <a href="#" class="link3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="work-A-link2">A2<br />
<a href="#" class="link1">1</a> <a href="#" class="link2">2</a> <a href="#" class="link3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="work-A-link3">A3<br />
<a href="#" class="link1">1</a> <a href="#" class="link2">2</a> <a href="#" class="link3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="work-B-link1">B1<br />
<a href="#" class="link1">1</a> <a href="#" class="link2">2</a> <a href="#" class="link3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="work-B-link2">B2<br />
<a href="#" class="link1">1</a> <a href="#" class="link2">2</a> <a href="#" class="link3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="work-B-link3">B3<br />
<a href="#" class="link1">1</a> <a href="#" class="link2">2</a> <a href="#" class="link3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="work-C-link1">C1<br />
<a href="#" class="link1">1</a> <a href="#" class="link2">2</a> <a href="#" class="link3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="work-C-link2">C2<br />
<a href="#" class="link1">1</a> <a href="#" class="link2">2</a> <a href="#" class="link3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="work-C-link3">C3<br />
<a href="#" class="link1">1</a> <a href="#" class="link2">2</a> <a href="#" class="link3">3</a>
</div>
```

And here's the code to go with it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div[class^=work-]').hide();
$(".A").click(function() {
    $("div[class^=work-]").hide();
    $("div[class^=work-A-link1]").fadeIn();
});
$(".B").click(function() {
    $("div[class^=work-]").hide();
    $("div[class^=work-B-link1]").fadeIn();
});
$(".C").click(function() {
    $("div[class^=work-]").hide();
    $("div[class^=work-C-link1]").fadeIn();
});
$('[class^=link]').click(function() {
    $('div[class^=work-]').hide();
    var $this = $(this);
    var x = $this.attr("className");
    $(".work-A-" + x).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
});
```

This code only works with the div "A", and I'd have to number each div individually, which seems really inefficient. I've tried using split() to gather up the class names and target the respective divs, but I don't have the coding skills. Is there an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a different way if you can split up the classes in your HTML?

e.g. the divs which are

`<div class="work-A-link1">`

can you change them to?

`<div class="work A link1">`

if so this appears to work.. <strike>will add a fiddle a bit later</strike> added fiddle

```
$('.work').hide();
   $(".thework a").click(function() {
      var letter = $(this).attr("class"); // link class is also in work class 
         $(".work").hide(); // hide all work class
         $(".work.link1."+letter).fadeIn(); //show the relevant work class
   });


   $('.work a').click(function() {
     var pLink = $(this).attr("class"); //gets the link# class
     var pLetter = $(this).parent().attr("class").split(' ')[1]; //gets the relevant letter if letter is 2nd class in array  index 1

     if ($(this).parent().hasClass(pLink)) {
        //do nothing
     } else {

     $(this).parent().hide();
     $("." + pLetter + "." + pLink).fadeIn(); // produces the .letter.link# CSS selector required
   }

   return false;
});
```

#### Working Example : [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/XLgjH/)

Comment: @clairesuzy: That works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time and your elegant coding skills!

Comment: @clairesuzy: Gah! Now that I have put content into the divs (images and text between <p> tags), the click function has rendered them 'active' and an inadvertent click makes the div disappear (they fulfill the hide but not the fadeIn requirements). If I give the content a class, can I add a statement into the if/else so that a click does nothing?

Comment: would need to a sample of your new code, perhaps stick it in a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) for brevity.. my code should only activate on the click of a link, perhaps you've changed `$('.work a').click(function()` or there are more links in your content, if the latter you will need to give the "activating" link another class to target it more specifically

Comment: [**here's an updated one**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/bxsFC/), you had too much hiding attached to your new divs `faber` and `wandw` they don't need 'hide on click' actions, the about and contact wrappers would never be open when your sub divs (`.work`) are open, as you've already had to close them to get to the "work00" wrapper

Comment: the main problem was that you had your `wandw` and `faber` divs closing themselves on click - `"div[class^=work]").hide();` - both those divs are also class `work`

Comment: @clairesuzy: Bear with me, I'm trying to digest that. So all my extra bits have broken your code? Ah. The fiddle you linked to [link](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/bxsFC/) still behaves broken to me, though. Thanks for you patience.

Comment: it's OK no hurry, I'm nearly off to bed though! ;) - No your bits didn't break my code, they were just doing extra things by themselves, e.g. when you had `div[class^=work]").hide();` attached to `faber`, `faber` is already `.work` too so by clicking ion it it was hiding itself, what's not working the way you want in the new fiddle?

Comment: oh shoot I linked to your original one!! dohh.. need to refind my one .. it' time for bed defintiely.. back it a minute -  [here try this one](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/NSB38/).. sorry, no wonder it didn't make sense LOL!

Comment: @clairesuzy: That works brilliantly, thank you. I'll have to get my head around what you did in the morning. Good night!

Comment: @clairesuzy: Now I see - lots of schoolboy howlers in my code. Thanks for clearing that up, and thanks for your elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div[class^=work-]').hide();
   var letters = ["A", "B", "C"]; //Put all posible letters here
   for(var i in letters){
      var letter = letters[i];
      $("."+letter).click(function() {
         $("div[class^=work-]").hide();
         $("div[class^=work-"+letter+"-link1]").fadeIn();
      });
   }
   $('[class^=link]').click(function() {
      $('div[class^=work-]').hide();
      $(this).parent().fadeIn(); //This does the trick!!
      return false;
   });
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Many thanks for doing this - unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Clicking 'A', 'B', or 'C' shows only 'C1'; also the links within 'C1' are inactive.