# Problem with sub-menu showing/hiding on click

Tags: javascript

I followed a great example of how to make a sub-menu appear/disappear on click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924353/jquery-show-hide-multiple-divs-from-menu-and-menu-within-div) and made it work. Quite an accomplishment since I'm just starting with javascript.  But just as I made it work a few other problems came up, I'll try to explain:

1.- I have a vertical main menu and one of the options, 'Products' has a sub-category that opens on hover below the parent item.  When selecting one of its sub-categories, a bigger menu shows up in a new div to the right of the main menu.  When this happens, the selected sub-category changes color and displays a bullet so the user knows which sub-category they are viewing.  I was doing this using PHP to detect the current page and assign an "active" id.  But when I had it like that the sub-menu show/hide didn't work and all the options were showing when first entering the page.  So I changed the link reference from "page.php" to "#" ­---which makes more sense since that option is not meant to be a link rather than just display another sub-menu but had to include it for the sake of displaying the 'active' id--- and now the show/hide works except after I click a sub-category, the menu to the right opens, but the previously selected sub-category that opens on hover closes and the php detect function doesn't work because I changed the reference to "#" and the link doesn't show an 'active' status; in fact, the 'home' option stays selected even when the second div is already showing.

It sounds confusing, I know.  [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/brunn/tkVfX/2/) the example, I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do.  I'd appreciate if anyone knows a way around this.

2.-  Once I can get this fixed, is there a way to make the second div slide from left to right instead of fading in?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post the created html into js fiddle, not the php version...

Comment: You can't post PHP into JSFiddle. you need to post the resulting HTML. Also, you have a misunderstanding of how to use `id` and `class`. `id` is used to identify a specific item, whereas class defines a group of items, or adds additional properties to an item. `<a href="#" class="app" id="active">` should be `<a href="#" id="app" class="active">`. The other benefit to this is that you can easily swap the active class around... `$('#app').removeClass('active'); $('#acc').addClass('active');`

Comment: Done, removed the php part.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: No... the HTML box can not have any `<?php ... ?>` tags. I updated it for you. (http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/tkVfX/1/)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save my changes, already updated link in OP.  Thanks Dutchie432.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my update to your code.. http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/tkVfX/4/

**CSS**

```
.mainNav {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color: #e21a22;
}
.active{
 font-weight:bold;
}
.mainSide {
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Helvetica,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
    padding-top: 40px;
    width: 143px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.mainSide li a, .mainSide li {
    color: #fff;
    width: 143px;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mainSide ul li a {
    width: 125px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 6px 0 2px 18px;
}

.mainSide li a:hover {
    color: #fdb046;
}

.mainSide li a#active, .mainSide ul li a#active {
    color: #fdb046;
    background: url("../img/bullet.jpg") right center no-repeat;
}

#subNavSys, #subNavApp, #subNavAcc {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color: #414143;
    display:none;
}

#subSideSys, #subSideApp, #subSideAcc {
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Helvetica,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
    padding-top: 163px;
    width: 143px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#subSideSys li a, #subSideSys li, #subSideApp li a, #subSideApp li, #subSideAcc li a, #subSideAcc li {
    color: #fff;
    width: 143px;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#subSideSys li a:hover, #subSideApp li a:hover, #subSideAcc li a:hover {
    color: #fdb046;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainNav">
        <a href="index.php"><img id="top" src="img/metal.jpg" width="143" height="43" alt="Index" /></a>
        <ul class="mainSide">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About us</a></li>
            <li>Products
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" id="sys">By system</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="app">By application</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="acc">Accesories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="subNavSys">

        <ul id="subSideSys">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-menu-1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-menu-1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-menu-1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="subNavApp">
        <ul id="subSideApp">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-menu-2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-menu-2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-menu-2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="subNavAcc">
        <ul id="subSideAcc">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-menu-3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-menu-3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-menu-3.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#sys").click(function() {

        $("#subNavApp").hide();
        $("#subNavAcc").hide();
        $("#subNavSys").fadeIn(800);
        $('*').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $("#app").click(function() {
        $("#subNavSys").hide();
        $("#subNavAcc").hide();
        $("#subNavApp").fadeIn(800);
        $('*').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $("#acc").click(function() {
        $("#subNavSys").hide();
        $("#subNavApp").hide();
        $("#subNavAcc").fadeIn(800);
        $('*').removeClass('active');        
        $(this).addClass('active');        
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dutchie432, I looked up some CSS docs about id's and classess and you were right, I already updated my code per your suggestion.  However my original problem remains, I can't get the current section to show 'active' state.  In the code you provided the selected option is shown in bold font but if I add a color it doesn't show it.  Plus, any idea about how to make the sub-menu (by sys, by app and accesories) stay open when it is selected and not just on hover?  I appreciate the time and effort you put into this.

Comment: The reason your colors aren't showing up is the you need to update your `active` class's CSS to to include the `visited` case. `active, .active:visited{font-weight:bold;color:#00f;}` see update (http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/tkVfX/6/)

Comment: Glad to help. Happy Coding. PS - you should click the checkmark next to my answer so people will know that this helped you in the future.

Comment: Hi Dutchie432, if you're still around could you help me with something else?  The last class you helped me with (.active:visited to add a color and a bullet) does work in Opera and Chrome but I was just checking in ff and, while it does shows the bullet, it does not display the color.  Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Fixed it.  Just added "#menu li .active" :)